# How to search specific user on smack

Tags: java, smack, asmack

For few hours I've stucked this issue. I'm learning smack API. The problem is when I'm searching for the buddy(user) it's giving all matched options.
For example I have these users:
-user
-user1
-user2

Searching "user" returning all these users. I want to be returned only one user which is matched exactly. How can I do this?

```
Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search.localhost");
Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();

answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);
answerForm.setAnswer("search", "user");

ReportedData data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm, "search.localhost");
....
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search the exact jid. If your service name is localhost and you are searching for "jid", you have some options:

`answerForm.setAnswer("search", "user@localhost");`

or

`answerForm.setAnswer("search", "user" + "@" + connection.getServiceName);`

or

`answerForm.setAnswer("search", "user@" + connection.getServiceName);`

How to use the ReportedData:

```
    if (data != null) {
       List<Row> rows = data.getRows();
       Iterator<Row> it = rows.iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           Row row = it.next();
           List<String> values = row.getValues("jid");
           Iterator<String> iterator = values.iterator();
           if (iterator.hasNext()) {
               String value = iterator.next();
               //Do what you want
           }
       }
    }
```